Luke 19 says believers will have authority over cities. What does this say about life in the new heavens and new earth?

Luke 19:12-27 ESV
He said therefore, "A nobleman went into a far country to receive for himself a kingdom and then return. Calling ten of his servants, he gave them ten minas, and said to them, 'Engage in business until I come.' But his citizens hated him and sent a delegation after him, saying, 'We do not want this man to reign over us.' When he returned, having received the kingdom, he ordered these servants to whom he had given the money to be called to him, that he might know what they had gained by doing business. The first came before him, saying, 'Lord, your mina has made ten minas more.' And he said to him, 'Well done, good servant! Because you have been faithful in a very little, you shall have authority over ten cities.' And the second came, saying, 'Lord, your mina has made five minas.' And he said to him, 'And you are to be over five cities.


Then another came, saying, 'Lord, here is your mina, which I kept laid away in a handkerchief; for I was afraid of you, because you are a severe man. You take what you did not deposit, and reap what you did not sow.'  He said to him, 'I will condemn you with your own words, you wicked servant! You knew that I was a severe man, taking what I did not deposit and reaping what I did not sow? Why then did you not put my money in the bank, and at my coming I might have collected it with interest?' And he said to those who stood by, 'Take the mina from him, and give it to the one who has the ten minas.' And they said to him, 'Lord, he has ten minas!' 'I tell you that to everyone who has, more will be given, but from the one who has not, even what he has will be taken away. But as for these enemies of mine, who did not want me to reign over them, bring them here and slaughter them before me.’” …

Those who were faithful to use the minas that God gave them were rewarded to have authority to rule cities. What does this say about the life to come?

Revelation 21:1-4 ESV
Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and the sea was no more. And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying, "Behold, the dwelling place of God is with man. He will dwell with them, and they will be his people, and God himself will be with them as their God. He will wipe away every tear from their eyes, and death shall be no more, neither shall there be mourning, nor crying, nor pain anymore, for the former things have passed away."


Are these details meant to tell us anything more than "this life will be preferable to the alternative"? Are we currently capable of comprehending any clearer picture?

There are myriad opinions about this, but any answer would be speculation. Should not the final word on this lie with the Apostle Paul who wrote about a man he knew who was caught up to the third heaven? "...and was caught up into paradise, and heard unspeakable words, which it is not lawful for a man to utter." 2 Cor.12:2-4 Surely we dare not go beyond that?

I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for theological synthesis, rather than the exegesis of one specific passage.

Please accept my apology for question being modified- it was way too broad in scope

The new heaven and new earth will be God resetting and recreating the heavens and the earth for believers of Jesus Christ, where sin and the effects of sin will no longer be present. One will be able to enjoy the beauty of God’s presence in all of His glory, unhindered by the presence of sin.
Let's consider some verses.
New creation:
Isaiah 65:17 says, “For behold, I create new heavens and a new earth; And the former shall not be remembered or come to mind.”
God’s presence:
As you pointed out, Revelation 21:3 says, “And I heard a loud voice from heaven saying, “Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and He will dwell with them, and they shall be His people. God Himself will be with them and be their God."
Absence of sorrow and death:
Revelation 21:4 says, “And God will wipe away every tear from their eyes; there shall be no more death, nor sorrow, nor crying. There shall be no more pain, for the former things have passed away.”
Righteousness dwells:
2 Peter 3:13 says, “Nevertheless we, according to His promise, look for new heavens and a new earth in which righteousness dwells."
Endurance of God’s people:
Isaiah 66:22 says, “For as the new heavens and the new earth
Which I will make shall remain before Me,” says the Lord,
“So shall your descendants and your name remain.
No more curse:
Revelation 22:3 says, "And there shall be no more curse, but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it, and His servants shall serve Him."

+1.  Good answer that correctly avoids specifics - the Bible says very little to nothing about heaven except the character of the people who will inhabit heaven.

Much appreciated @Dottard .

As Paul writes in Romans 14:17: "the Kingdom of God is not a matter of eating and drinking, but of righteousness, peace and joy in the Holy Spirit".
Thus, to know what is the life in the Kingdom of God is to know what is righteousness, peace and joy in the Holy Spirit. But this knowledge is impossible unless one experiences it through a practice. You can read thousands of books about swimming and the joy of immersing oneself in the waves of the sea, but it will not be a knowledge, but just a pile of sterile informations. How can I, a vindictive, pusillanimous avenger know what the joy of forgiving is, if I only read about it and hear about it in Church, but, if fact, am as degeneratedly vindictive as any other mafioso is?! Ha?!
Or, how can a womanizer know what is the joy of chastity through Holy Spirit's grace, unless he abandons this bed habit and chooses one lifelong partner of love?! Impossible! Imagine your, a chain-smoker's, lungs listen thousand times per day dreamlike stories of lungs of olympic swimmers who are enjoying fresh air all day long; will your lungs really know what the life of those other, healthy lungs are? Not really! Stop smoking and your lungs will get a chance to get a glimpse of it!
Thus, the knowledge of the Kingdom of Heavens is an experiential knowledge and the real knower also participates in the life of this Kingdom. And it does not start only after the physical historical life, but already during our historical lives. Moreover, unless you know already here, in this life, what the joy of Holy Spirit is through your ascetic struggle agains the sin and darkness, you will not inherit the Kingdom of Heaven after the end of this life either! Impossible! For we continue in the afterlife those things that we start doing here: if we collaborated with God's Spirit and adhered to Christ's commandments, we shall pre-taste the life and joy coming from Holy Spirit already here and then continue with it in a more intense way in the afterlife; but, if, on the contrary, we live according to worldly things and taste only worldly pleasures and understand only worldly values, then the afterlife, where the worldly values will be abolished, will be a torment to us. If you are accustomed to Justin Bieber's noises, that laughably usurp a name of "music" for them, then in a place where J.S. Bach's music sounds and Bieber's noises are annulled, you will feel yourself in a hell, when lovers of the good music, on the contrary - in a bliss.
Sorry Muslims, no 70 virgins, interchangeably every day, in the afterlife. In fact, to have sex with 70 virgins daily is hardly a bliss but a penal servitude.
